# I have a problem with the event loop in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game where the player is constantly in the middle when and the background moves to make it seem like the player's moving. When I press two arrow keys Ex. up and right, it goes diagonally, but when I let the up-arrow go it should keep going right. Sometimes it works, but mostly it just stops moving.

I have no idea how to fix this.

### event loop

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[K_UP]:
        if key[K_RIGHT]:
            bg.move("up_right")
        elif key[K_LEFT]:
            bg.move("up_left")
        else:
            bg.move("up")

    elif key[K_DOWN]:
        if key[K_RIGHT]:
            bg.move("down_right")
        elif key[K_LEFT]:
            bg.move("down_left")
        else:
            bg.move("down")


    elif key[K_RIGHT]:
        if key[K_DOWN]:
            bg.move("down_right")
        elif key[K_UP]:
            bg.move("up_right")
        else:
            bg.move("right")


    elif key[K_LEFT]:
        if key[K_DOWN]:
            bg.move("down_left")
        elif key[K_UP]:
            bg.move("up_left")
        else:
            bg.move("left")
```

### movement

> Here the movement gets changed

```
def move(self, direction):
    if direction == "up_right":
        self.posY += self.speed
        self.posX -= self.speed

    if direction == "up_left":
        self.posY += self.speed
        self.posX += self.speed

    if direction == "down_right":
        self.posY -= self.speed
        self.posX -= self.speed

    if direction == "down_left":
        self.posY -= self.speed
        self.posX += self.speed
        
    if direction == "up":
        self.posY += self.speed+2
        
    if direction == "down":
        self.posY -= self.speed+2
        
    if direction == "right":
        self.posX -= self.speed+2
        
    if direction == "left":
        self.posX += self.speed+2
```

At first, I didn't add in the "up_left", etc. because I thought it would just go through both ifs and edit the position on both. But it didn't.

I'm sorry if there are already answers to this topic, but I couldn't find any.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you check for the pressed keys inside your event loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    # only executed if there's an event returned by pygame.event.get()
    # and possible executed multiple times per frame
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[K_UP]:
        ...
```

Therefore, your code that does the movement (`if key[K_UP]: ...`) is only executed when there's currently an event in the queue.

Just move this code outside the event handler loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

# always executed every frame
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if key[K_UP]:
     ...
```

---

IMHO a better way to handle your movement is to use vectors, since they make it easy to ensure a constant movement speed and it's much less code.

Here's a simple example:

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0

    movement = {
        pygame.K_UP:    ( 0, -1),
        pygame.K_DOWN:  ( 0,  1),
        pygame.K_LEFT:  (-1,  0),
        pygame.K_RIGHT: ( 1,  0)
    }

    pos = pygame.Vector2((100, 100))

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # calculate the movement vector
        move = pygame.Vector2()
        for dir in (movement[key] for key in movement if pressed[key]):
            move += dir

        if move.length() > 0: move.normalize_ip()
        # ensure we have a constant speed
        pos += move * dt/5

        screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), [int(x) for x in pos], 20, 0)
        pygame.display.update()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Everything works fine now. I'll try to implement the vectors too.